# json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type graphql.httpPostBody

Tags: json, graphql, httpclient, cloudflare

We are trying for GraphQL Analytics API of cloudflare, we are trying to post this query through HttpClient

In response we are getting the error

> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type graphql.httpPostBody

This is the query we are getting after the SerializeObject

```
"query{viewer {zones(filter: { zoneTag: \"XYZ\"}) {httpRequests1dGroups(orderBy: [date_ASC], limit: 1000, filter: { date_gt: \"2021-06-09\"}) {date: dimensions {date}sum {cachedBytes bytes}}}}}"
```

What is that we need to correct here, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Direct JSON Post Will not Work.

You will have to use .NET GraphQL Packages to form proper query and get responses back.

1. GraphQL.Client
   https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL.Client/3.2.4/
2. GraphQL.Client.Serializer.Newtonsoft
   https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL.Client.Serializer.Newtonsoft/3.2.4/